# In Jasperreports how do you set a margin on a page with a background color?

Tags: background, jasper-reports, margin

I'm using JasperReports to generate a report and my .jrxml looks like this for setting a background color.

The problem is that I need to have a margin on the page but the margins appear white. I've tried adding a box with padding to the background which doesn't work because it's the background

```
<background>
        <band splitType="Stretch" height="842">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="595" height="842" backcolor="#DEEBF9" />
                <box topPadding="20" leftPadding="20" rightPadding="20">
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </background>
```

**EDIT** picture was requested.

I'm seeing the left when I am trying to create the right. The margins are excluding the background color because I need to reduce the width of the background band. Otherwise I get the "Margin and background exceed page size " exception. How do I either color in the margins or create some kind of padding that affects the entire page apart from the background?
[image]

Comment: As your question is about report design, can you provide some pictorial representation of your result which you are getting and your expected result.

Comment: Hi. Have you found a solution?